# Create a port forward proxy to accelerate the network

Tags: python, twisted

I've found a project called [Tunnel Spliiter](http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2010/01/10/tunnel-splitter-accelerating-a-single-tcp-connection-over-multiple-isps/) which does what I want, but it is not available anymore.

So I would like to start it from scratch with python. But I'm not quite familiar with tcp/ip programming, so I would like to start from some simple acts - just create a port forward proxy and make it multiplex to maximize the use of bandwidth, so seems like PortForward provided with Twisted meets my requirement.

But I couldn't find any information of how to make a single connection multiplex, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does it mean to "make a single connection multiplex"?  Can you describe your requirements in terms of concrete tasks, accepting a TCP connection, establishing new outgoing TCP connections, and the specific way which data moves between the connections?

Comment: @Jean-Paul Calderone The link the author provided, does a bit of explanation. In short he wants to split up TCP connection to use multiple connections. I would imagine that this might be used for ISP connection load balancing when uploading /downloading large files.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone thx jbreicis ,just like he said,a snippet trying to split a single tcp connection to multiple tcp connection to utilize bandwidth usage. In most case single connection will not fill up the whole bandwidth so I just thought to do so. I just did a little modifications with PortForward proxy and tries to give a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Got time to think about this and probably PortForward is not the thing you want to proceed.

If I were to create something like this, I would do it this way:

LOAD_BALANCED_APP <-> [LOCAL_SOCKS_SERVER -- (de)multiplexer] <->UDP<-> [(de)multiplexer -- REMOTE_SOCKS_SERVER] <-> SERVICE

Where you could take Socks implementation from the Twisted, split the receive and transmit logic into two seperate pieces with a (de)multiplexer acting as a glue between these two frankensteins. I would suggest that you start with a (de)multiplexer logic and iron that out first: use of different number of connections, restoring the exact stream on the other end, process lost connections and lost dialog sequences. When you have that in place, working and generalized - I am thinking of two pairs of consumer/producer per box, adding Socket server or any other Proxy like service for that matter should be a breeze.

Comment: Hi,really appreciated for your advice,I've already worked it out with that last week. I used a control channel(a independent TCP channel from client to server side) to do the splitting and glueing things, also some producer/consumer pasuee/resume logics, and attached with a sequence mark to prevent from connectionLost for retransfer. PortForward is a good start though, I still have to rewrite most of the logic,but it really save a huge bunch of time to help me out with how to get it started.

Comment: Dont use seperate TCP channel for signallng. Thus you make the redundancy of your link as weak as that connection where the signaling runs on. Think of it as this - if that link broke down, your server and client would not be able to make head or tail of the flow without the signaling. You should rather aim for signallng embeded in all of the channels, sent out on all of the channels at the same time. As there is not much to signal, that should not add a massive overhead. Then from the receiving side, you would process the first message and discard the others with same signaling_msg_id

Comment: I've tested it this weekend and runs pretty smooth. When signal channel goes down it will purge all of the workers(multiple tunnels created for exchange data) and connections and wait for client to auto-reconnect,and it is rarely happened(mainly caused by network problem). To do so because I want to employ SSL channel on signal channel to exchange keys for workers(using ssl for worker channel will be really expensive), and worker were introduced just for data exchanging without knowing any infos of message or any other connection details.